# Python Remove single quotes from Pandas data frame weird output

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe I have a string column as shown below

```
acctno
'12345
 12345
 12345-5678
```

I am trying to remove the Single quote(') in the Column .
I ran the below code

```py
df['acctno'] = df['acctno'].str.replace("[']", "")
```

The output is not what i expected

Output"

```
acctno
12345
nan 
12345-5678
```

Trying to understand why 12345 value without single quotes is being removed instead of leaving it as it is.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: use regex----->   df['acctno'] = df['acctno'].str.extract(r'\d+(-\d+)?')

Comment: Are you sure that's purely a string column?  Your code works perfectly for me.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got the following error
ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me too!  Can't simulate your error case.

Comment: what error did you get, try it again

Comment: @TimRoberts 
acctno                 12865 non-null  object

Comment: @SeaBean It's replacing the Single quote but it's making my values which doesn't have single quotes to nan not sure why it's happening

Comment: @Ade_1 this is the output i got when i tried your solution
acctno
nan
nan
nan
-5678

Comment: Could you please make a `df['acctno'].to_dict()` to dump the contents.   Also, what's your Pandas version ?

Comment: Yes, we don't have all of the information here.  I like SeaBean's suggestion; let's see some real data.

Comment: @SeaBean i think it's reading the particular value as Int
Key type Size
0     Str     1       '12345
1     int      1        12345
2     Str      1        12345-5678
so what should i do as it's reading that value as int while others as Str

Comment: One workaround would be to convert the column to string before replace character.  eg. `df['acctno'].astype(str).str.replace("[']", "")`   if you intend to have all values being strings here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend the column to have only strings and got the integer input as error, you can also convert it to string before the clean up of single quote character, e.g. by:

```
df['acctno'] = df['acctno'].astype(str).str.replace("[']", "", regex=True)
```

### Demo

```
data = {'acctno': {0: "'12345", 1: 12345, 2: '12345-5678'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['acctno'] = df['acctno'].astype(str).str.replace("[']", "", regex=True)


## Without NaN now 

       acctno
0       12345
1       12345
2  12345-5678
```